# Pointer declaration syntax error on cdecl org

Tags: c

While trying to read a complicated pointer declaration using the site, I noticed that a simple declaration like `int * ptr` leads to a syntax error. I cant seem to understand why. [image]

Comment: Looks like a bug on cdecl.org to me. The don't like the `ptr` identifier for some obscure reason. `int *foo` works, `int *ptr` fails as you describe.

Comment: I think the reason is because you can enter english and it gives C too, so if you type `declare foo as ptr to int` it gives `int *foo`. I assume this means that `ptr` is some special keyword.

Comment: That site is broken in general. Contact the site owner.

Comment: As @mediocrevegetable1 mentioned those are some special keywords. If you want to read the details about those errors you can check the issue at github [link](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/cdecl-blocks/issues/18#issuecomment-703120081) and the actual code [here](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/cdecl-blocks/blob/ac818eae23deabee8718b52a7607fdda9fd9f393/cdlex.l#L32).